# How to check for changes in a List in java?

Tags: java, list, synchronized, java-threads

I have a question, I want to know if it's possible to check continuously for adds to a list.

I have a node with a file to transfer, I connect it to a directory.
I have another node without the file and requires a download, I also connect it to the directory.

What is currently happening is:

```
Node 1 Port 40
```

And after I add the second node, only then does the SECOND node know there's him and another node:

```
Node 1 Port 40
Node 2 Port 60
```

But the first one, he still only sees himself. So my question is, how can I make the first node, or all the nodes, continuously check if there are new ones added to the list.

```
  public void addExistingNodes(String sta) {
    if (sta.equals("end")) return;
    if (!(checkNodesList.contains(sta))) {
        checkNodesList.add(sta);
        nodes.add(new Nodes(checkNodesList.get(checkNodesList.size() - 1)));
    }
}
```

This code is used to avoid, the following:

```
Node 1 Port 40
Node 1 Port 40
Node 2 Port 60
```

In case you stop the process without closing the directory.

Comment: You're looking to implement the observer pattern.  See: https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern

Comment: I would consider adding a "observable" wrapper around something like an `ArrayList`.  You don't want to "continuously monitor" the state of the list, it's inefficient

Comment: How would I do that @MadProgrammer ? Is it as Amir suggested? Since in the jdk 17, overservable has been deprecated

Comment: @Box Conceptually, it's the same as Amir, except I'd probably roll my own wrapper, but now I'm intrigued by [`java.util.concurrent.Flow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html) 

Answer (score 1):

A **REALLY** basic idea of a "observable list".  Please note, I consider this a "basic" implementation, I only support `add` and `remove`, and while I've taken some steps to ensure thread safety, there is still more which could/should be done to prevent possible multi-thread mutations of some of the states

The demonstrates the basic concept of produce/consumer and observable pattern

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        ObservableList<String> list = new ObservableList<>(new ArrayList<String>(8));

        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            private Condition con = lock.newCondition();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.addObserver(new ObservableList.ObservableListListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void listDidAddValue(ObservableList<String> source, String value) {
                        System.out.println("Did add " + value);
                        lock.lock();
                        try {
                            con.signal();
                        } finally {
                            lock.unlock();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void listDidRemoveValue(ObservableList<String> source, String value) {
                        System.out.println("Did remove " + value);
                        lock.lock();
                        try {
                            con.signal();
                        } finally {
                            lock.unlock();
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        lock.lock();
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Waiting for something to happen");
                            con.await();
                        } finally {
                            lock.unlock();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Something happended, process it...");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        consumer.setDaemon(true);
        consumer.start();

        try {
            // Give the consumer timer to spin up ;)
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        Thread produce = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String text = "Hello world";
                    for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
                        String value = text.substring(index, index + 1);
                        list.add(value);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++) {
                        String value = text.substring(index, index + 1);
                        list.remove(value);
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("All done here, leaving now");
            }
        });
        produce.start();
    }

    public class ObservableList<E> {

        public interface ObservableListListener<E> {

            public void listDidAddValue(ObservableList<E> source, E value);

            public void listDidRemoveValue(ObservableList<E> source, E value);
        }

        private List<E> backingStore;
        private List<ObservableListListener<E>> observers;

        public ObservableList(List<E> list) {
            this.backingStore = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
            observers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(8));
        }

        public void add(E value) {
            backingStore.add(value);
            fireDidAddValue(value);
        }

        public void remove(E value) {
            boolean removed = backingStore.remove(value);
            fireDidRemoveValue(value);
        }

        public int size() {
            return backingStore.size();
        }

        public void addObserver(ObservableListListener<E> observer) {
            observers.add(observer);
        }

        public void removeObserver(ObservableListListener<E> observer) {
            observers.remove(observer);
        }

        protected void fireDidAddValue(E value) {
            if (observers.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (ObservableListListener<E> observer : observers) {
                observer.listDidAddValue(this, value);
            }
        }

        protected void fireDidRemoveValue(E value) {
            if (observers.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            for (ObservableListListener<E> observer : observers) {
                observer.listDidRemoveValue(this, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also encourage having a look at [Java 9 Reactive Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-reactive-streams) which would seem to fulfil your overall needs